# React updating state within the same component

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react, I thought setting state will re-render react component. Did I miss something here, my text is not displayed until I call `this.forceUpdate()`.

```js
export default class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: ''};
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);   
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange}   />
            <p> You entered {this.state.value} </p>
        </div>
    );
  } 

  handleChange(event){      
    this.state = { value: event.target.value };     
    this.forceUpdate();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call [`.setState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate) method instead of assign new value to `this.state`

```
handleChange(event){      
  this.setState({ value: event.target.value })
}
```